# Flutter setState() doesn't reactive to the List data change

Tags: flutter, list, setstate

When I click on the floating button, trying to make the widget change, but no success，why?

The element data of the List has indeed changed, but the widget has not been updated synchronously.

This problem confuses me and don't know how to solve it?
I want the ListView widget to respond to changes in the List's data.

main.dart

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'video_model.dart';
import 'video_item.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  var videos = [
    VideoModel(title: 'a', intro: 'x'),
    VideoModel(title: 'b', intro: 'y'),
    VideoModel(title: 'c', intro: 'z'),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            videos = [
              VideoModel(title: 'c', intro: 'o'),
              VideoModel(title: 'd', intro: 'p'),
              VideoModel(title: 'f', intro: 'q'),
            ];
          });
        },
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        physics: const ScrollPhysics(),
        itemCount: videos.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          var video = videos[index];
          return VideoItem(video);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

video_item.dart

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'video_model.dart';

class VideoItem extends StatefulWidget {
  final VideoModel video;
  const VideoItem(this.video, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<VideoItem> createState() => _VideoItemState();
}

class _VideoItemState extends State<VideoItem> {
  late VideoModel video;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    video = widget.video;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Text(video.title),
          const SizedBox(width: 16),
          Text(video.intro)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

video_model.dart

```dart
class VideoModel {
  String title;
  String intro;

  VideoModel({
    required this.title,
    required this.intro,
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `video_item.dart` you are setting the video variable inside the `initState` which only runs once, so whenever you use `setState` only the `build` method gets called again. thus the `video` variable in the `_VideoItemState` is never set again, so it stays with the same old value

you can simply just use the video coming in the `VideoItem` constructor like this

```
children: [
      Text(widget.video.title),
      const SizedBox(width: 16),
      Text(widget.video.intro)
    ],
```